# Is there a Bootstrap CSS class appropriate for a div or a span that will make it look like an input?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, input, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to have some readonly data on the page that I want to put in a `span` or a `div`. And I would like this to look like a Bootstrap input field. This is similar to giving the class `btn` to a div to make it look like a button.

Comment: I don't know whats the use case here, but there is a `readonly`-attribute which you can assign to a input tag to make it readonly. The appearance varies though (compared to the standard input). see http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-readonly

Comment: I don't want to have the mouse pointer icon changing. Also I need to set the value inside the `<span>` using `innerHTML`. I also don't want a `textarea` and make it look like a simple input (resizing control, line count, etc.)

Comment: @GabrielPetrovay Will you mark my answer?

Answer (score 13):

```
<fieldset disabled>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="disabledTextInput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Disabled input and select list (Fieldset disabled)</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" id="disabledTextInput" class="form-control" placeholder="Disabled input">
            </div>
          </div>
</fieldset>
```

Working fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/4bvsbkr2/2/

Update

```
  <fieldset disabled>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="disabledTextInput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Disabled input and select list (Fieldset disabled)</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <span class="form-control">
                  Disabled
                </span>
            </div>
          </div>
</fieldset>
```

Fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/4bvsbkr2/15/

Comment: This does not work for me because I want instead of `<input>` a `<span>` or a `<div>` to set its innerHTML property.

Comment: If you want to remove cursor disabled, add class and change cursor property

Comment: Or just <span class="form-control" disabled>
                  Disabled
</span>

Comment: Yes, this looks great! Thanks! So you can do it with `form-control`